# How did Scirra get HTML5 audio so perfect in Construct 2?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, construct-2

Check out [this space shooter demo](http://www.scirra.com/construct2/demos/space-blaster).

The HTML5 audio is *perfect* on Chrome 18 and Firefox 10. There is no lag in playing sounds and each sample plays perfectly. The last time I tried to play sounds using HTML5 audio and JavaScript I couldn't get a sound to play more than once.

What sorcery is Scirra doing to make this so perfect?

Comment: Tom here from Scirra, I'll see if I can get Ashley to answer this for you shortly!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I'm the developer of Construct 2, so I hope I'm sufficiently qualified to answer your question :)

HTML5 audio is indeed a mess, so I've gone to considerable lengths to try and make it bulletproof in Construct 2.  Here's an outline of what I've done:

**Use the Web Audio API**

HTML5 audio appears designed for streaming music, so a HTML5 Audio object is kind of a heavyweight object.  Playing 10 sounds a second with it like Space Blaster does can easily seize up the browser.  On the other hand, the Web Audio API is a high-performance audio engine with routing, effects, and lightweight sound playback.  It's perfect for games.  Audio buffers and audio playback are separated, so you can have one data buffer and efficiently play it many times simultaneously, whereas some browsers are so buggy if you play a HTML5 sound a few times it re-downloads it each time!  Since it was actually designed for games and such, you can happily play back tonnes of sound for ages and it will still hum along nicely.  It can also use HTML5 audio as a sound source, although I only use HTML5 audio for things the user has designated as music tracks (since that's where you'd prefer to have streaming - typically everything else in the Web Audio API is fully downloaded before playing).

The Web Audio API is supported in Chrome, has also made it in to iOS 6+ (although it's muted until you try to play some audio in a touch event), Firefox are working on support, and it should be coming soon to Chrome for Android. So on these platforms audio will be significantly more reliable.

More info on [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) and [the proposed spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) - you'll have to use the spec as the documentation for now, there's not much else out there.

**Other browsers: implement an audio recycling system**

The Web Audio API isn't yet supported everywhere, notably IE, which means you still need to crowbar HTML5 audio in to something that might work for games for backwards compatibility.  The way to do this is to recycle audio objects.

The player's laser in Space Blaster fires 10 times a second - and that's not including any other sound effects!  As I mentioned earlier, Audio is kind of a heavyweight object, so if you're doing `new Audio()` 10+ times a second, lo and behold, the browser eventually dies and audio starts glitching up.  However, you can drastically reduce the number of Audio objects created by recycling them.

Basically, for each sound effect, keep a cache of every Audio object you've created with that sound as a source.  Then, when playing a new sound, search the cache for any sound effects which have finished playing (the `ended` property will be true).  If you find one, rewind it back to the beginning (`currentTime = 0`) and `play()` again.  Otherwise, create a `new Audio()` object in the cache.

Since the player's laser sound effect is short, instead of creating 600 Audio objects a minute, there will just be 3 or 4 that it keeps cycling round.  Some browsers unfortunately will still download it 4 times (Safari did this last I checked!) or have high latency the *first* time each sound buffer is played, but eventually the browser catches up since the same buffers are always being reused.  So basically sound might be a bit weird for a few moments, then it clears up.  We also use the HTML5 app cache so next time you play everything loads from disk, so subsequent plays should perform well immediately.

That's basically it.  It's still a little dodgy on the first play with HTML5 audio, but every time after that should be fairly solid providing the browser has a sane audio implementation.  There are a number of ways to try to clone Audio objects, but I've found that rewinding existing Audios works best.

There's no SoundManager or any Flash/plugin-based fallbacks at all since we make a point of being pure HTML5.

We also support audio APIs provided by PhoneGap and appMobi for mobile, since HTML5 audio on mobile isn't even worth trying.  That makes a total of four audio APIs our audio engine wraps, and yes, it does look like a frankenstein mess, but it works.

That's it.  I suppose our competitors will read this, but who cares when there's SO rep to be had???!!!1111

Comment: I am not a web dev, but I saw this url from Twitter, and I love to read about techniques and frameworks. Shortly said: +1

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you! I'm guessing that, since you want people to use Construct 2, you're not planning on releasing this component as a stand-alone library...

Comment: Well the reality is we're working round the clock on our startup already, so we just don't have time, and as you say it would slightly disincentive our engine... although I'm perfectly happy for anyone to use my post as a basis for a new open source engine!

Comment: Edited to add more up-to-date content since it's been about a year and the question seems popular!

Comment: Nice answer. I have found an open-source library that provides the functionality that is described in this answer, called howler.js. Here is a demo: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library and here is the source code: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js